# Paginate items after filtering by ajax

Tags: django, ajax, filter, checkbox, pagination

guys!
I have a page with brands and two checkboxes list, category and country. I realized filter logic by  jsonresponse, and ajax:

[its my filter view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emVjv.png)

[its my checkbox template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbWbm.png)

[its my js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VObc.png)

[its a part of my page template my filter view work for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4KLn.png)

[and finally, all my page template looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6F6k.png)

its all work correctly. now I need add pagination, but I have a problem - my checkboxes filtering rendered by filter_data view, and my main page template rendered by another view, this:

[my main view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uBlxT.png)

so, when I try add paginate to my filter_date view, calculations my objects by paginator works good, but when i submit to the second page, logic stop working. I have no idea, how to realize this, please, help me ;)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.